# What is the difference between realised and decided?

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence

> Hazel says 'funerals I'd decided are for the living, not the dead'.

Shouldn't there be **realised** instead of **decided**?

Answer (score 2):

To '**realize**' something is to:

> Become fully aware of (something) as a fact; understand clearly

and to '**decide**' something is to:

> Come or bring to a resolution in the mind as a result of consideration.

Now, when the speaker/ author says that she has '*realized*', it means that she has been made aware of the fact that funerals are for the living, and not for the dead. This may come as a new piece of information, at which point this realization struck her mind. She may have come to this conclusion as a result of her awareness from recent events.

Had she '*decided*' that '*funerals are for the living, and not for the dead*', it would mean that she knew that there was a possibility of this statement being true, from her experiences from funerals, from recent events, as well as from her past. A '*decision*' involves coming into a conclusion, based on evaluation of available information.

So, if she had '*realized*' something, it would mean that she gained the knowledge recently, but if she had '*decided*', it would mean that she had gained awareness of this knowledge earlier, and came to a conclusion that this is the valid inference from various possibilities.

Comment: You mean realisation happens naturally and when we decide something it is the conclusion of what we have been thinking?

Comment: You could say that, in a very generalized view.